# renormalization and relativity

Tags: energy, renormalization, mass-energy, qft-in-curved-spacetime

So my issue is the seemingly paradoxical view in QFT that we renormalize energy with the argument that energy is relative and only a convenience introduced for calculations originally while relativity implies energy and inertial mass are equivalent (related through the 4 momentum). Clearly that seems to suggest energy of particles are physical and thus absolute in some sense as is their mass. Are we even referring to the same concept of energy here?

Comment: The renormalization of energy is Lorentz invariant

Comment: any more explanation?

Comment: You can perform it by adding a counterterm of $\rho$ to the Lagrangian, which is a lorentz invariant scalar.